# Axis scaling in batch mode

Tags: xmgrace

I am using gracebat of xmgrace to generate bar graphs using the following batch script.

```
s0 line type 0
S0 SYMBOL COLOR 4
S0 SYMBOL FILL 1
s0 type BAR
## Bar fill. Only 1 (black) is available.
 S0 FILL WITH COLOR
 S0 FILL COLOR 3
## Outline width.
S0 SYMBOL LINEWIDTH 2
# options for image output
WORLD XMIN 0
WORLD YMIN 0
PAGE SIZE 800, 600
```

The first issue that sometimes the script automatically sets the 0.5 spacing on X, while I need always 1. Here is the example:

[image]

How I could eliminate those unused 0.5 spacings via some option in my batch file?

The second problem (again on X axis): sometimes the graph cover wider range of values on 2 without any of data:

[image]

Is it possible to automatically limit XMAX according to the initial dataset (but without its seting manualy in batch script since I apply it to different xvg files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I could eliminate those unused 0.5 spacings via some option in my batch file?

With `XAXIS TICK MAJOR 1`.

> Is it possible to automatically limit XMAX according to the initial dataset?

The [documentation](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/commands.html) says

> graphno AUTOSCALE TYPE SPEC
> Set the method of autoscaling to use the minimum and maximum values of the data.

So one could think `G0 AUTOSCALE TYPE SPEC` would do it, nevertheless it does not, at least not in the stable version of Xmgrace.

An alternative is to extract the maximum values of the X and Y axis from the data file with a program (say, `awk`), and use that to generate the appropriate batch commands. Say, save this as `batchplot`:

```
awk '
  NR==1{
    max1=$1
    max2=$2
  }
  $1>max1{max1=$1}
  $2>max2{max2=$2}
  END{printf "WORLD XMAX %s\nWORLD YMAX %s\n",max1,max2 >> "a.xmg"}
' a.dat
xmgrace -nosafe -batch a.xmg a.dat
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x batchplot`, substitute `a.xmg` and `a.dat` by the name of the batch and data file, and then just run it.
It will append the X and Y axes limits to the batch and then run it.

Advice: If you are planning to use more complicated plotting features, the command-line interface of Xmgrace will prove to be a pain. This and [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615860) already indicate so. In that case, I recommend GNUPlot or Matplotlib, which were born to be scriptable.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions! Yes, it would be interesting to look on AWK expression (if it is not something very complicated, that I could use for pre-processing of XVG filles). I suppose I need some AWK script, which would scan XVG file and capture its Xmax (I don't care about Ymax presently) in a distinct variable, that I will use in my batch script as XMAX, isn't it?  if it is nessesary I can add example of XVG to my first post...

Comment: @user3470313 I have added how you would go about that in Awk. Yes, it captures the maximum X and Y in max1 and max2 variables and then appends the batch statement to the batch file.

Comment: yes! I've adapted your AWK sollution with my bash script and it works fine and do fantastical job. Thank you again! One question: is there some option for batch file to demonstrate always XMAX and YMAX on the corresponded AXES ? sometimes this marker is missed on graph ( I attach a picture to my first post)

Comment: @user3470313 You are welcome. That happens whenever the major ticks interval is not a multiple of the minor ticks interval, so there is nothing you can do, sorry.

Comment: hello, I've just fixed it via addition of +1 to xmax and xmin in your AWK script in order that the both axes always have 1 additional point in both directions .. :-)  END{printf "WORLD XMAX %s\nWORLD YMAX %s\n",max1+1,max2+1      sorry I don't know a proper syntax of AWK but functionally it works well

Comment: @user3470313 Alright, I thought you meant you wanted the last tick of the axis to always appear, which only happens in the case I meantion in the previous comment.